# CEWP does not support <form> tag in jQuery file

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, cewp

I added jQuery to my Sharepoint page. When I reference the jQuery file uploaded in my library, I get this error message:

> `<FORM> tags are not supported in the HTML specified in either the Content property or the Content Link property. You can remove the``tag, or use the Page Viewer Web Part, which supports the HTML`<'FORM'>` tag. The Content property can be modified in the Rich Text Editor or Source Editor. More about the Page Viewer Web Part*

I checked the jQuery file and I found a Form tag, when I delete it the script does not work anymore.

Here's a screenshot ( in french ) 
[image]

In jQuery file ( the official jQuery library )  :

[image]

May it be because of this line ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues referencing my .js file directly from a CEWP. What I do is reference a .txt or .html file that has a reference to my .js file. If this doesn't work then you have an error in your .js file.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

it's jQuery file from Jquery website. It's just that CEWP when Including the file it detects <Form> tag. And that's not allowed. I don't know how to do to solve that..

Comment: ah, so sharepoint already has a <Form> tag that exists in the masterpage so you can't include another one, but the removal of the form tag from your file shouldn't prevent it from displaying ... can you upload your code or part of it?

Comment: OK i put to date my post

Comment: Have you tried using the .min version of jquery?  It seems odd to me that SharePoint isn't just removing the forms tags...and it seems even more odd that jquery is trying to put form tags into your page.

Comment: same thing.. It contains <form>. 

and when I try to make a test in a script web part , the code pasted in disappear ..

Comment: which version of jquery are you trying to use?

Comment: 3.1.1 jQuery version

Comment: Not sure why this would cause an issue but try using the latest version of jQuery 1.x

Answer (score 0):

Actually it won't matter if you will contain your form inside a '' tag (in sharepoint, there trapping it to block some unknown server side actions), you can still do it inside  or any block elements, you will just need to wrap your function call in your button call it with jquery.

```
<div>
      <input type="text" id="mytextfield">
      <button id="mytextfield">Click me</button>
<div>
```

//on javascript file run the event with jquery

```
$("mytextfield").click(function(){ //run button logic })
```

Hope the concept helps, Happy coding!